# XAMPP Mac: "Unable to create directory" error

Tags: mac, xampp

I just installed XAMPP on Mac OSX.

When I tried to install a theme into a newly created WordPress site, I got this error:

Unable to create directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Anyone know how to make a directory writable on Mac OSX? version 10.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sudo with Anne's answer if you are still having the problem (As evident from the comment). That should do the trick.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
```

Comment: Setting web folders to use `777` introduces a major security risk. It should be avoided where possible.

Comment: just make sure 777 is right for you